# Finding, hex-editing date timestamp to correct it

Tags: file-format, hex

Trying hex-editing to fix the date-time data in file which was generated while the computer system clock was wrong. Some tutorial will be helpful appreciated after my attempts so far.

[screen shot attached-- WRONG DATE-- surrounded in bold-red box]

[image: Screenshot of incorrect dates in Hex Editor]

My attempts:

- Changing the text by typing in the right characters:-- doesn't work, date turns into "not available" when file is opened with the OEM software.
- Deleting all boxed text and typing in the right date:-- file won't open at all using the OEM software.

Comment: NOTE: for the editing by simply typing in new characters (replacing the old), the applied edits correctly shows in the OEM software only if the new date-time is at a future point relative to the existing "Dec 30, 2015  03:23:10"

Comment: I see this is from the program [Sciex Analyst](http://sciex.com/products/software/analyst-software). What does the function call-stack look like when `FMWIFFCompDocNTDriver.dll!GetFieldC_csChecksumTimeStamp` is called?

Comment: is there some sort of CRC in the file that makes the file invalid when opened with the OEM software?

Answer (score 1):

Surfing the net about WIFF file formats, I found two software that convert WIFF file to others formats:

- [Proteowizerd](http://proteowizard.sourceforge.net/formats.shtml)
- [wiff2dta](https://sourceforge.net/projects/protms/files/wiff2dta/)

You can check if there are bytes used to check the data in addition to the chunk that you have already tried to patch (d5a0 -> d640).